# Samsung's "Device maintenance" on Galaxy S8

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

Samsung have had their "Device maintenance" functionality for a while (named "Smart Manager" on Galaxy S6 and Galaxy S7). Our app has had no issues with it before Samsung Galaxy S8. Earlier it has deleted cached files and while it may cause the user to use more data to download some assets one more time it has worked as expected.

However, on Galaxy S8 there seems to be some change in what the app deletes. It seems to delete some private app data that is actual valuable to the user and that we can't just recreate. It looks like it keeps .db files and possible shared preferences, but other files are not to be found after the user has pressed the "Optimise now" button.

I wonder if **a) anyone else is seeing this**, and **b) is there some kind of official or unofficial documentation saying what Samsung will delete and how to somehow say which files to stay away from?**

Comment: There are a high probability that this is happening with our app too. The S8 constantly loses session tokens and/or states saved.